# C# How do I write to a text file?

Tags: c#, file, file-io

Online subject. Teacher gave us this but it doesn't run. Throws an error on line 48 where the fileWriter.WriteLine is
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Online tutorials look completely different

```
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        private StreamWriter fileWriter;

        public class Record
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Suburb { get; set; }
            public decimal Fee { get; set; }

        }

        string fileName = "student.txt";


        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FileStream output = new FileStream(fileName,
                FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            fileWriter = new StreamWriter(output);
        }
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Record record = new Record();

            record.Name = txtName.Text;
            record.ID = txtID.Text;
            record.Suburb = txtSuburb.Text;
            record.Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(txtFee.Text);

            fileWriter.WriteLine(record.Name + "," + record.ID + "," +
                record.Suburb + "," + record.Fee); // Error here


            txtName.Text = "";
            txtID.Text = "";
            txtSuburb.Text = "";
            txtFee.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `frmMain_Load` isn't hooked up, click on the load event in the properties of the IDE, and select that method.

[image]

[image]

Badly hewn circle added for your enjoyment

Comment: He hasn't even talked about anything like that but yeah that fixed it, thankyou